# How can I get permission correct throughh GUI on Linux 20.04

Tags: linux, backup, permissions

How can I get permission correct through GUI on Linux 20.04 please?

Every morning at Backup time I see the dreaded panel.. Back Up Failure  -Need permission.

I have 3 drives and I am trying to backup to a new drive I just added into the box.

I do not know enough command Linux to fix this myself even though I have tried.

Need some guidance please.

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed description of the permission error? What have you tried to resolve the issue and what research have you done? Also please fix the grammar in your question to maintain the high quality standard on superuser.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am not sure what I did to fix it, however it seems it is okay now. I tried many commands however I think this is what did it. 
sudo chown -R $USER$myusername /var/www/ my folder I need to get to.

Comment: Whilst it worked for a while, I am now getting the same error panel again. It says.. Backup Failed.    Error creating directory /media/david/Backup_Drive2TB: Permission Denied.   I see in the Files GUI Backup_Drive2TB   1.4TB / 2.0TB available /dev/sdd1